# Passing a "this" pointer to a free thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm looking for a pattern or set of classes to deal with the following:

I have a class that is going to start a "child thread" which is going to run some code, and then make a callback on the class that launched it.

There is a chance that the object that launched the thread, and is awaiting the callback may be destroyed by the time the function returns. I've thought of rolling my own solution where I'd wrap the "this" pointer in a set of classes which would:

1. Allow the caller to "notify" thread that is going to be using the "this" pointer that it's pointer is no longer valid because it's being destructed.
2. Allow the "child thread" prevent the destruction of the "this" pointer when its making the callback.

The idea is that I'm looking for a way for a "free" thread (i.e. thread::detach has been called) to make a callback on an object that may have been destructed without throwing an exception.

Basically I have some UI elements that are launching threads, passing callback functions as "continuations". The problem is that the UI elements may be destroyed by the time the new thread is complete.

Comment: You probably wan't to notify the thread using a condition variable and apply a `join()` in the destructor corresponding to `this`.

Comment: You can't join a detached thread. And, yes, you do not want to ever do a callback to a destructed object. No idea what sorts of stuff "this" points to. Condition variable and mutex protection seems advisable. Thread can self destruct if either the callback object no longer exists or after it returns from the callback.

Comment: There's something that's really bad about your question: You are asking how to solve something in a very specific way, but you don't even mention the actual problem! That then leads to contradictions like that you want the "child thread [to] prevent destruction", but want some way to "callback on an object that may have been destructed". BTW: There is no parent-child relation between threads and calling functions on destroyed objects causes so-called "undefined behaviour", it doesn't throw an exeption that you could handle.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - I think the last paragraph explains the problem. I have UI elements, whose code is running in a UI thread. On some user interactions, I want to launch a thread to retrieve data, and when complete, callback to the UI element so that the data can be displayed. The issue is that by the time the callback completes, the user may have performed another action which may have destroyed the original UI element. Yes, I can roll my own solution with mutexes, but I was looking to see if there was a pattern or set of classes that would solve this issue.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - doug is right, I'm using a detatched thread so we can't join.